# Cypress cannot connect to edge browser when run in gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab-ci

I use Cypress to run autotests on three different browsers.
When I run "npx cypress run --browser edge" in my laptop's terminal, everything goes well.
But I need to run tests in Gitlab Runner which was also installed on my laptop.
For some reason Cypress is unable to connect to Edge if tests are run in Gitlab CI.

I tried to specify the path to the msedge.exe file, but it does not help.

I also tried updating Edge, that didn't help either.

Pipeline Log:

```
$ npm ci
added 420 packages, and audited 421 packages in 5s
59 packages are looking for funding
  run npm fund for details
5 moderate severity vulnerabilities
To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
Run npm audit for details.
$ npx cypress run --browser edge
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65337/devtools/browser/7843c549-1df9-4b1c-93fb-82dbe7e25596

Running:  NegativeSecretTest.cy.js                                                        (1 of 4)
Still waiting to connect to Edge, retrying in 1 second (attempt 18/62)
Still waiting to connect to Edge, retrying in 1 second (attempt 19/62)

...

Still waiting to connect to Edge, retrying in 1 second (attempt 61/62)
Still waiting to connect to Edge, retrying in 1 second (attempt 62/62)
All promises were rejected
AggregateError: All promises were rejected
```

Please tell me why he can't connect to Edge even though he sees it?  Below command is run from gitlab-ci.yml

```
$ npx cypress info
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52737/devtools/browser/4133ec34-d667-4557-9038-761a0f0d35da
Displaying Cypress info...
Detected 3 browsers installed:

2. Edge
  - Name: edge
  - Channel: stable
  - Version: 114.0.1823.86
  - Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
  - Profile: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Cypress\cy\production\browsers\edge-stable


...
```